# vagrant pip install svn+https://.. Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled

Tags: python, svn, pip, vagrant

How can I make automated scrip with Vagrant + pip & svn ?

Installing without vagrant (svn asking credential via promt console) [OK]:

```
# file:system/vagrant_setup.sh
sudo pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv
sudo mkdir -p /opt/python-env2/
sudo chown vagrant:vagrant /opt/python-env2/
cd /opt/python-env2
virtualenv env-appserver

# requirements-stable.txt contains
# svn+https://svn.company.ch/svn/integration-2014-sep-24@1886#egg=integration
/opt/python-env2/env-appserver/bin/pip install -r /vagrant/requirements/requirements-stable.txt
```

Installing with vagrant (svn DO NOT asking credential) [FAIL]:

```
# file Vagrant
Vagrant.configure("2") do |o|
    #o.vm.box = "Official Ubuntu 11.10 Server amd64"
    o.vm.box = "trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1"
    o.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
    o.vm.synced_folder "./opt/proj", "/opt/proj", create:true
    # this did not helped o.vm.synced_folder "~/.subversion", "/home/vagrant/.subversion", create:true
    o.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.55.55"
    o.vm.provision :shell, :path => "system/vagrant_setup.sh"
end
```

Error log bellow:

```
# file:log
==> default: Downloading/unpacking integration from svn+https://svn.company.ch/svn/integration-2014-sep-24@1886 (from -r /vagrant/requirements/requirements-stable.txt (line 4))
==> default:   Checking out https://svn.company.ch/svn/integration-2014-sep-24 (to revision 1886) to ./env-appserver/build/integration
==> default: svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
==> default: svn: E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn.company.ch/svn/integration-2014-sep-24'
==> default: svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
==> default: Authentication failed
==> default:   Complete output from command /usr/bin/svn checkout -q -r 1886 svn.company.ch/svn/integration-2014-sep-24 /opt/python-env2/env-appserver/build/integration:
==> default:   
==> default: ----------------------------------------
==> default: Cleaning up...
==> default: Command /usr/bin/svn checkout -q -r 1886 svn.company.ch/svn/integration-2014-sep-24 /opt/python-env2/env-appserver/build/integration failed with error code 1 in None
==> default: Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your provision script system/vagrant_setup.sh is trying to do a `svn checkout` and failing authentication.  You will have to pass your credentials to the svn server with the --username and --password options to svn checkout.  Look at `svn help checkout` for more information.

Your next hurdle is going to be getting svn to be quiet about all of its confirmations.  For example, to stop it from asking you if you want to store passwords in freetext everytime you try to authenticate to a server, you may want to add

```
echo "store-plaintext-passwords = no" >> /home/vagrant/.subversion/servers
```

to your system/vagrant_setup.sh script.  Of course this file must exist first, so you can either copy a full version of it or try to get subversion to create it automatically with a `svn help` sudo'd as the vagrant user first.  (Otherwise the .subversion folder will be in the /root/ folder.)  Note that subversion creates the ~/.subversion folder and all of it's contents the first time it is run by a user.

It's a bit tricky to get this all set up, but I think the payoff will be great in mass producing developer sandboxes.